# Error: $injector:unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

My service:

```
angular.module('app').factory('keretHttpSrv',  function ($http, $state, $scope, $rootScope, $q, $localStorage) {
/*some code*/
    return keretHttpService; 
})
```

My controller,

```
angular.module('app.dashboard')
.controller('DashboardCtrl',
 ['$scope', 'keretHttpSrv', function ($scope, keretHttpSrv)
 {
/*some code*/
 }])
```

I have this error:

> Error: $injector:unknown provider

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have the injections for the controller, but none for your factory?

Comment: injector order will also much matter

Comment: you mean this :
angular.module('app').factory( keretHttpSrv,  function (

[ '$http','$state','$scope','$rootScope','$q',$'localStorage',

$http, $state, $scope, $rootScope, $q, $localStorage)


I tried, but all the same I have error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no `$scope` for a factory

FIX

```js
angular.module('app').factory('keretHttpSrv',  function ($http, $state, $rootScope, $q, $localStorage) {
/*some code*/
    return keretHttpService; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the 'keretHttpSrv' factory to the 'app' module and adding the 'DashboardCtrl' controller to the 'app.dashboard' module. To access the factory you will have to either inject the 'app' module into 'app.dashboard' when you define it

```
angular.module('app.dashboard', ['app']);
```

or put both the factory and the controller in the same module

```
//first define the module
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').factory('keretHttpSrv',  function ($http, $state, $scope, $rootScope, $q, $localStorage) {
/*some code*/
    return keretHttpService; 
})

angular.module('app')
.controller('DashboardCtrl',
 ['$scope', 'keretHttpSrv', function ($scope, keretHttpSrv)
 {
/*some code*/
 }])
```

Comment: How are you defining your modules?

Comment: angular.module('app').factory('keretHttpSrv',  function ($http, $state, $scope, $rootScope, $q, $localStorage) { ... })



angular.module('app').controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope, keretHttpSrv, $rootScope, $document, $compile, $localStorage) { ... })

Comment: I think that is your problem. To define a new module you have to pass in an array of dependencies (it can be blank). I have updated my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: I understood. You mean this?



inline `angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngResource'
])

.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            views: {
                "content@app": {
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html'
                }
            }.....   `

I have 3 js-files(service.js, controller.js, and module.js). And module.js contains this code

Comment: Which Provider is it saying is missing?

Comment: `[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=<div data-ui-view="content" data-autoscroll="false" class="ng-scope">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20keretHttpSrv`

Answer (score 0):

do you need to use routing here
you have two option :

1. `angular.module("app",['ngRoute'])`;

it is lib in angular but the second option is better

2.`angular.module("app",['ui.router'])`;

after you need to config the provider of $state in

```
angular.module("app",['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider,...){};
```

all about ui router u can read here [UI ROUTER](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router)

and see example here [Examples](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)